# Incorrect Syntax near 'b' and failed to convert date or time

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, sql-convert

I have 2 queries.

The first one got an error message that it failed to convert date or time

```
select a.ProductID, sum(a.Quantity) as Qty ,SUM (a.SubTotal) as Sub
from TransactionDetail a join Transactions b on a.TransactionID = b.TransactionDate
group by productID
```

So I tried to convert date and time as follows

```
select  a.ProductID, sum(a.Quantity) as Qty ,SUM (a.SubTotal) as Sub
from TransactionDetail a join Transactions b on a.TransactionID = (Convert(varchar(10),b.TransactionDate,101)) b.TransactionDate
group by productID
```

but now I got this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: `= (expression) b.TransactionDate` <-- exactly what did you miss after the parenthesis here before the `b`? Or... exactly what did you forget to *remove* after you changed the sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
 = (Convert(varchar(10),b.TransactionDate,101)) b.TransactionDate group by productID
```

is what the server is complaining about.

Specifically, here is the `b` the error message is referring to:

```
                                                v
 = (Convert(varchar(10),b.TransactionDate,101)) b.TransactionDate group by productID
```

Most likely you *inserted* the new parenthesized expression but forgot to remove the part you had there before. In other words, you likely want to simply remove this section:

```
                                                v---------------v
 = (Convert(varchar(10),b.TransactionDate,101)) b.TransactionDate group by productID
```

Comment: @fadoewae: If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.